# if string in list fails with diacritics

Tags: python, diacritics

As I'm French, I'm trying to make a little function that can add the good definite article before a country name. I have no problem except for the few countries that start with a diacritic. Here's my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def article(nomPays):
    voyelles = ['A','E','É','I','O','U','Y']
    if nomPays == 'Mexique':
        return 'du'
    elif nomPays[0] in voyelles:
        return 'de l\''
    elif nomPays[-1] == 'e':#signe négatif pour compter à partir de la dernière lettre
        return 'de la'
    else:
        return 'du'

print article('Érythrée')
```

If I enter Allemagne instead of Érythrée, the behaviour is correct : it returns 'de l''. But Érythrée returns 'de la'. It means my function doesn't recognize the character É as part of the voyelles list.

Can anyone explain me why and how I can resolve this?

Comment: Mandatory reading: [The Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: And of course the [Joel Spolsky classic on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `str` in Python 2, where `str` is a sequence of bytes and so `nomPays[0]` will give the first *byte* of the string, not the first *character*.  In single-byte encodings this isn't a problem, but with multi-byte encodings like UTF-8 the first byte of "Érythrée" is a *lead byte* and not the whole character "É".

You need to change to use `unicode` to grab the first character:

```
firstChar = unicode(nomPays, 'UTF-8')[0].encode('UTF-8')
```

Actually, it'd probably be easier to use `startswith`:

```
if any(nomPays.startswith(voyelle) for voyelle in voyelles):
```

Alternatively you could use `unicode` throughout your application, or switch to Python 3, where all this is handled much better.

Comment: Very clear and  precise answer. For now I'll use `startwith` but i'll consider switching to Python 3. And thanks also to @martjin for the reading advises (already done for the first one).

Answer (score 3):

Add `u` before `''`:

```
voyelles = [u'A',u'E',u'É',u'I',u'O',u'U',u'Y']
...
print article(u'Érythrée')
```

Example:

```
>>> voyelles = [u'A',u'E',u'É',u'I',u'O',u'U',u'Y']
>>> s=u'Érythrée'
>>> s[0] in voyelles
True
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a byte string, not a unicode string, therefore the first element of the string is:

```
>>> 'Érythrée'[0]
'\xc3'
```

This is because of the UT8 encoding.